# Problems with migrations in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration

Something really weird is going on with my Laravel setup. I create some migration files and, when running `php artisan migrate` after creating each of them, they were successfully run and the tables were created in the database. Now, if I want to run `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`, it cannot rollback one of the migrations because it says that migration file doesn't exist.
This is the error:
[image: It says the migration was not found]
And this is my migration file:
[image: The file exists!]

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAssessmentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('assessments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            //TODO - Complete information for this table
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('assessments');
    }
}
```

What's even weirder is that I had to re-create all migrations because it was randomly not creating some of the tables listed on the migrations.

Did anyone face this issue before? Any help is really appreciated.

**[UPDATE]**

After a while, I realized this is not something from Laravel. For some reason, my Homestead is not viewing those files despite there are there. If I access that folder via SSH (the one inside the vagrant box), the file is not there. If I go to the real folder, it is there. For some reason the box is not synching files properly.
What's even weirder is that I can access and edit the file inside the VMB but it won't list it and won't take into account when running migrations. Here I created a [screen-recording showing the problem](https://www.useloom.com/share/caf51d7a6fcf427b8f288f9f80203a95).

**[UPDATE 2]**

Just recorded 2 more videos. This is really strange (unless I am missing something).

[Video 1.](https://www.useloom.com/share/5243438990d84ad2bc6317352da2cef2)

[Video 2.](https://www.useloom.com/share/6d859d77bf674ea9a6c70e23dce2e966)

Comment: Since the migrations are stored in a table, I could see this happening if you are checking out different branches in git which don't have those migrations and trying to run the commands.  Is that a possibility here?

Comment: can you put your code of the seeder file?

Comment: Nope, everything is running in the same branch @user3158900

Comment: @JamesRiady how would my seeder code help? It doesn't change anything. It's the migration file the one that's not being found. It won't work even if I don't seed it.

Comment: have you tried to do `composer dump-autoload` in your cmd(laravel project)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with MacOS High Sierra and Vagrant. In order to fix it, I had to apply this [workaround](http://www.qed42.com/blog/macos-sierra-issues-vagrant).

Hopefully this will save some time to the ones having the same problem I was having.